# Is it possible in php to set super globals to a linked list data structure?

Tags: php, casting, superglobals

Is it possible in php to set super globals to a linked list data structure?

Kinda like:

```
$_GET = (SplDoublyLinkedList)$_GET;
$_GET->setIteratorMode( SplDoublyLinkedList::IT_MODE_DELETE );
```

I can manually create a linked list and put them into it. I am wondering if there is a way to cast a superglobal some how.

Comment: In php super global variable can be define using `$GLOBALS` [Super Global Variables in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)